# C# how to get a return in a void event args?

Tags: c#

In this code, in the event that my Player levels up, my other method responds in an equation, or so it seems, I can't return `bool` whether my player leveled up or not and hence, can't run another method.

```
private static void Obj_AI_Base_OnLevelUp(Obj_AI_Base sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Game.PrintChat("you leveled up!");
    bool levelup = true;
}

public bool results()
{
    return levelup;            
}
```

This is the theory that I want working, but realistically I can't do it because `void` cannot return, but how do I change/adapt this code to do the function? How do I re-work this code to get the `bool` when player levels up?

Comment: You could make the level up variable a class field and check it in the update function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
private static bool levelup = false;
private static void Obj_AI_Base_OnLevelUp(Obj_AI_Base sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Game.PrintChat("you leveled up!");
    levelup = true;
}

public bool results()
{
    return levelup;            
}
```

Comment: close, but as long as levelup is outside void Obj_AI_Base, i wont know whether the event happened or not :/, results() is always gona return true whether the player leveled up or not